# Inserting a value to a custom column via DataGridView of VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

My problem was, I created a custom Column I named it to "seat"

My program works but there is something missing about the code, and I don't know how to solve it, I debug all i can, i used msgboxes just to show the countVal value, and it works when it comes to MsgBox, but their is something wrong about this line of my code

```
dgSection.Rows.Item(startVal).Cells("seat").Value = countVal
```

That line of code only shows the output once, but if I clicked again the button to shows up the Form with DataGridView, the only things that will be showed up are the "SELECT statements" columns from my tables, while the custom column "Available Seat" is empty.

I already tried to use, refresh, Datasource = Nothing, rows.clear(), but their is no effect at all.

Could you guys help me about this problem?, I appreciate any feedback, thank you

---

```
    If dgSection.Columns.Contains("seat") = True Then
        dgSection.Columns.Remove("seat")
    End If

    FillGrid("SELECT SID,year_level,EntryID,Section,Year,MaxNumber FROM tbl_section LEFT JOIN tbl_personal_data ON tbl_section.Year = tbl_personal_data.year_level WHERE SID = " & frm_Enroll.SID, "tbl_section", dgSection)
    dgSection.Columns(0).Visible = False
    dgSection.Columns(1).Visible = False

    dgSection.Columns.Add("seat", "Available Seat")

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim startVal As Integer = 0

    For i = startVal To dgSection.Rows.Count - 1
        Try
            DS = New DataSet
            DS.Clear()
            Comm = CONN.CreateCommand
            Comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_personal_data WHERE section_id = " & dgSection.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            DA.SelectCommand = Comm
            DA.Fill(DS, "tbl_personal_data")
            CONN.Close()

            Dim countVal As Integer
            For Each table As DataTable In DS.Tables
                countVal = countVal + table.Rows.Count
            Next

            MsgBox(countVal) 'this is working it shows the counted rows

            dgSection.Rows.Item(startVal).Cells("seat").Value = countVal 'there is something wrong about this line
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error number:" & Err.Number & vbCrLf & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Finally
            CONN.Close()
        End Try
    Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be you meant to loop through the rows with the i variable instead of startVal, since your code is always updating the same row:

```
'dgSection.Rows.Item(startVal).Cells("seat").Value = countVal
dgSection.Rows.Item(i).Cells("seat").Value = countVal
```

Comment: sorry sir but that is also not working, since my previous code was i and not startVal...

Answer (score 0):

try add this code

`dgsection.rows.add`
before
this
`dgSection.Rows.Item(startVal).Cells("seat").Value = countVal 'there is something wrong about this line`
and change the

```
dgsection.rows.item(startval)
```

to

```
dgsection.rows.item(i)
```

then tell me what happen.. or can you can printscreen

also i need to know, what is the problem show of the line?

Comment: this is not a message board and your post is not a complete, self-contained answer. please request clarification first via question comments and only then attempt to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
dgSection.Rows(startVal).Cells("seat").Value = countVal
```

Comment: Where should the author add this line?